# How to post raw body using the npm request package

Tags: javascript, json, post, npm, request

I want to post a request to a service using the [npm request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). The service accepts a request body of comma-separated numbers such as `1,2,3`, but when I post the request, the body is `"1,2,3"` instead, which the service does not recognise. I use the following code:

```
import request from "request";

export function getIt(numbers) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const uri = 'http://foo.bar/getIt';
     const numbersBody = numbers.join(',')
     console.log('post body: ', numbersBody) // prints 1,2,3
     request
       .post(
          uri,
          { json: true, rejectUnauthorized: false, body: numbersBody },
          (err, httpResponse, body) => {
              let error = err && err.message ? err.message : err;
              if (body && body._error_code) {
                  error = body.message;
              }
              if (error) {
                  reject(error);
              } else {
                  resolve(body);
              }
          }
      )
});
```

When I inspect the network traffic with Wireshark, I can see that the body becomes `"1,2,3"`. It seems to be because the request package writes it as a json object. I have tried to remove the `json: true` part of the option, and also tried changing it to `false`, but that throws an exception. So I don't know how to make the string be the raw body, without the quotation marks. Is there any way to make that happen?

Comment: Did you try to send it as an array instead of a string?

Comment: @baao Yeah, that makes the body become `[1,2,3]`